# Using cell array as input in Neural Networks Wizard in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cell-array

I have a 1x1000 cell array for 28x28 images of the digit 0. I am using this as the input in the Neural Network Wizard. But i am unsure as to what i should have in the target output section. I tried a simple 1x1000 array of zeros(0) and a 1x1000 cell array of zeros.

I am at a complete loss as to what the variable type for the target output should be.

If someone could help, it would be amazing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to classify images using a neural network, you need to deal with them as with a 1D array of pixels. So if you have an image `28x28` pixels, you have to reshape it to `1x784` array. If you have `1000` of such image, you will get a `1000x784` matrix.

You may ask, how the network should use the 2-dimensional information from the image. It should not do it! You can even shuffle all your `1x784` arrays **in the same way** and feed the network, the result will be the same.

What about the target? Let's say originally you have a `1000x1` vector with your labels. For a classification problem you need to transform this vector to `1000xN` matrix, where N is number of your classes. So if you are going to classify digits from `0` to `9` you need `10` classes. The rows of this matrix will contain only `0` and `1`. Each `1` depicts the current class.

As an example I took a set of hand written digits from [here](http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html). Each image has `28x28` pixels. The whole set has `10000` samples. Each pixel is coded by a number from `0` to `255` corresponding to the gray level. I normalized the numbers dividing them by `255`, so now I have a real number in the range `[0..1]` for each pixel.

You can download the preprocessed data set from [here](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/ml/digits.zip).

Here is your code:

```
load('X.mat'); %inputs
load('Y.mat'); %targets

net = patternnet(10); %a network with 10 units in the hidden layer

[net,tr] = train(net, X',Y'); %training stage
```

It will generate a network like this:

[image: neural network for classification]

The data set will be divided automatically to the training, validation and test sets.

The training progress can be observed here:

[image]

To see the network's precision you might want to have a look at the confusion plots:

[image: confusion matrix for training set]
[image: confusion matrix for validation set]
[image: confusion matrix for test set]

As you can see the results are pretty good. You can tune the network to get much better results.